# Polygon to raster without losing any polygons

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, polygon

I'm trying to convert polygons to raster. But the output raster dataset doesn't have  polygons which went into as input data. I need all the date in the attribute to follow with to the raster dataset as well.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using ARCGIS 10.1.

Comment: Please clarify what is going wrong: Do you get an empty raster? No output at all? A raster that is missing some of the smallest polygons?  It would also help to describe what procedure you have used to make the conversion--there is almost always more than one way to get things done in ArcGIS.

Comment: The tool I've used is "Polgon to Raster". The output are few raster (since they were polygons to begin with) that the input of polygons. e.g, so there are 20polygons and the output are only 14 rasters. I tried a few different options, i.e changing "Cell assignment types" in Polygon to Raster tool to the three choices present, such as CELL_CENTER, MAXIMUM_AREA and MAXIMUM_COMBINED_AREA, but the outputs are less than the input polygons.

Comment: Did you remember first to set the analysis environment's extent to cover all the polygons?

Comment: Where and how do I do that?

Comment: There should be an "Environments" button at the bottom of the tool's dialog, as I recall.  It opens a long dialog with many panels; you need to explore and understand them all in order to use the tools successfully, especially raster-based tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to choose one attribute for the extraction only. i am not sure whether arcgis can create multilayer tifs from several attributes in a polygon. are you sure that all your attributes are integer/ numbers?
if so, extract one raster by attribute and make a layer stack/raster merge afterwards.
you can buiöld a model of it to make it easier to use in further applications.

Comment: The attributes that I want to have transfer to the raster are all numbers, which are the acres, hectares, etc, so they are important. I don't know either if one can have several attributes for a raster file. When I do choose to take other attributes (like hectare), I get message that it "wasn't able to complete the task", but when  just use the ID, the resulting output are a few rasters with very useless info in the attribute table.

Comment: hi gunnar, are those values integers? maybe this causes the problem?!

Comment: regarding 20 polygons and only 14 rasters... normally you have 20 polygons and just one raster with cellvalues according to the extracted attribute of the polygon...

Comment: They are of intergers...